# Проблемы с использованием библиотеки MailKit

Tags: c#, многопоточность, mime

Использую библиотеку [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit). Вот код

```
currentOperationTioken = new CancellationTokenSource();
client = new ImapClient();

client.Connected += Client_Connected;

client.Authenticated += Client_Authenticated;

client.Connect("imap", 993, true);
client.Authenticate("login", "pass");

inbox = client.Inbox.GetSubfolder("some");

inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

inbox.CountChanged += Inbox_CountChanged;

client.IdleAsync(currentOperationTioken.Token);


lock (client.SyncRoot)
{
    foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen))
    {
        //var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
        Console.WriteLine(inbox.GetMessage(uid).Subject);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(inbox.Count);
}
```

На строке `foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen))`  ловлю вот такую ошибку :`"The ImapClient is currently busy processing a command in another thread. Lock the SyncRoot property to properly synchronize your threads."`
С потоками у меня все плохо, помогите разобраться пожалуйста как правильно сделать. Код, который находится в `lock` будет отрабатывать в событии `Inbox_CountChanged`, если я правильно понимаю, то под капотом `IdleAsync`, какой то вечный цикл, потому что у объекта `client` есть метод `Idle`, после которого код останавливается на мониторинге директории(Методом тыка проверял). Уже думаю над вариантов делать два объекта `ImapClient`, один для мониторинга директории на новые сообщения, второй для вычитки это директории, но мне это не нравится.
Пробовал сделать с использованием `await`. Выполнение останавливается на строке вызова асинхронного метода(Я так думаю), так как дальше ничего не происходит.

```
private async static void connectImap()
{
    currentOperationTioken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    CancellationTokenSource currentOperationTioken1 = new CancellationTokenSource();

    client.Connected += Client_Connected;

    client.Authenticated += Client_Authenticated;

    client.Connect("imap", 993, true);
    client.Authenticate("login", "pass");

    inbox = client.Inbox.GetSubfolder("some");

    inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    inbox.CountChanged += Inbox_CountChanged;



    await client.IdleAsync(currentOperationTioken.Token);

    lock (client.SyncRoot)
    {
        foreach (var uid in inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen))
        {
            //var message = inbox.GetMessage(uid);
            Console.WriteLine(inbox.GetMessage(uid).Subject);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(inbox.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, что косяк в IdleAsync. Так как ты этим кодом запускаешь асинхронное действие и не дожидаясь его выполнения лезешь работать с этим объектом дальше, хотя с объектом может происходить какая-то работа в другом потоке.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну да, я думаю что оно и не выполнится, так как этот метод, запускает мониторинг директории на новые сообщения. Что мне плодить объекты только остается? Я имею ввиду дублировать код для другого го действия?

Comment: Какую вы логику хотите описать данным методом? Подождать N-ое время, а затем выполнить поиск?

Comment: @iluxa1810 в событии Inbox_CountChanged обратиться к inbox и прочитать новые сообщения, но я не знаю как мне остановить Idle а после прочтения снова запустить.

Comment: А есть какое-нибудь свойство, которое показывает, что объект в состоянии ожидания? Или завести свое собственное свойство в классе. Когда переводите в состояние ожидания объект, то меняете значение свойства на True, когда выводите на False.

Comment: А что за класс `ImapClient`?

Comment: @VladD сторонняя библиотека https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Comment: @Winteriscoming: Хм, это важно, добавьте, плиз, в вопрос.

Comment: @Winteriscoming: Возможно, просто баг в их библиотеке.

Answer (score 2):

> Причина ошибки

Метод [IdleAsync](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapClient_IdleAsync.htm) асинхронный, возвращающий Task.

Не дожидаясь выполнения асинхронной операции, вы пытаетесь использовать синхронную версию метода, используя специальное свойство для синхронизации синхронных операций [SyncRoot](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapClient_SyncRoot.htm). 
Но ваша предыдущая асинхронная операция еще не завершилась, другой поток работает с клиентом. Соответственно и вы и получаете данную ошибку.

> Как правильно работать с клиентом?

Согласно документации, метод [IdleAsync](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapClient_IdleAsync.htm) переводит клиента в состояние IDLE(паузы). Чтобы клиента вывести из состояния IDLE(паузы) и завершить асинхронную операцию, вам необходимо для токена `currentOperationTioken`, который вы передали в качестве параметра функции, вызвать метод [`Сancel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd321703(v=vs.110).aspx). Тогда ваша асинхронная задача "начнет завершаться".

**Поэтому у вас должен быть следующий алгоритм работы:**
1. Вызываете асинхронный метод `IdleAsync`(без await), сохраняя в переменной возвращаемый `Task`
2. Когда вам необходимо что-то прочитать, сделать, обработать то, что получили от сервера, вы вызываете `Cancel` для токена, который вы передали в функцию в качестве параметра. 
3. Вызываете [`await`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await) для `Task`, который вернул вам метод `IdleAsync`, чтобы ТОЧНО дождаться завершения асинхронной операции . 
4. Выполняете обработку данных. 
5. После всей обработки, снова вызываете метод `IdleAsync`, переводя клиента в состояние IDLE, чтобы продолжить получать события от сервера.
И так далее.

Стоит еще отметить, что отмененный токен нельзя использовать повторно. Необходимо создавать все время новый токен с помощью класса[CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) для каждого вызова [IdleAsync](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapClient_IdleAsync.htm)

Comment: Я делал так, ошибка та же, сейчас дополню вопрос, возможно что то не так сделал.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Я думал он и так уходит в другой поток. В другой поток это типо так  Thread myThread = new Thread(client.IdleAsync) ?

Comment: другой поток, который запускает функцию, которая будет внутри себя делать client.IdleAsync до тех пор, пока  ей не скажут приостановиться. Далее после ваших действия, снова у вас какой-то поток делает client.IdleAsync

Comment: заработало, а как возобновить слежение, просто заново вызвать client.IdleAsync(currentOperationTioken.Token) ?

Comment: да, но нужно токен заново создать из класса Source

Comment: Как то туповато получается или мне так кажется?

Comment: Поток не нужен, достаточно не делать await :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, согласен, можно убрать await и просто делать Cancel

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov на самом деле, await желателен - но уже после Cancel

Comment: Такой вариант будет норм? 
        private static void StartIMAPWatcher()
        {
            using (CancellationTokenSource IMAPWatcherCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                client.IdleAsync(IMAPWatcherCancelToken.Token);
            }
        }

Comment: @Winteriscoming, идея пересоздания токена верная. Вызов без await тоже. А большего сказать нечего по этому куску кода.

Comment: Вы смогли добиться требуемого результата?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov нет. Мистика. Добился только создав еще одно отдельное подключение для вычитки.